# Amazon lex response card in Connect chat

Tags: amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I am working on amazon lex and integrating amazon lex with connect chat So, I used the response card in amazon lex but it didn't show in connect chat so is there any way to show the button response card in connect chat

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the exact same issue

Comment: Nope. Didn't find anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done (at this time - August 2021). However search for amazon connect interactive messages blog and you will find something usable